# How to expand neural network layer?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to write an expandable neural network described in this paper: Lifelong Learning with Dynamically Expandable Networks (Jeongtae Lee, Jaehong Yoon, Eunho Yang, Sung Ju Hwang, Aug 2017).

Now consider I have such a LSTM layer:

```
tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(128, state_is_tuple=True)
```

Say I want to leave the gates for now and just want to expand the neurons of this LSTM layer from 128 to 256 while retaining the previous weights and make the new weights 0.000001 which makes it insignificant for the following layers. How can I do that?

Also, is it possible to change the input size and retain the weights by assigning zero weights to the new features at the beginning? For example, if I have input like this:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 30, 2])
```

and I want to change it to:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 30, 5])
```

Then, what should I do to my layers to load the previously trained weights and padding zeros to fit the input shape?

An answer to any other types of layers will be very much appreciated as well. Literally, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not a good idea to put few questions in one

Comment: @ChaosPredictor sorry, that wasn't on purpose. The reason that I want to expand the layer is that a larger input contains more information which is too much for 128 neurons to learn. I will try to think of a way to better separate the question tho.

Comment: What kind of data are you using?

Comment: @ChaosPredictor I am using a sliding window on a series of number pairs, signal data. Basically a number stream of two channels. And later on, I want to expand that to more data channels, from 2 to 5 to virtually more in the future. Eventually, I want to run this on real-time, and that's why I want to expend network instead of having downtime to re-learn the model.

Comment: Break your problem to subproblems ask each one separately, with all the relevant information and steps that you already tried.

Answer (score -1):

1. New weights should be initialized to random values